# PHP - mysqli_query not working

Tags: php, mysql

i'm working in a crud with MySQL and PHP, when i try to insert in the Alumno table it works, but in the Matricula table not.
What can i do?
I tried with the mysqli_multi_query(), but don't work.
The data base is fine

```
include 'Conexion.php';
if(isset($_POST['Registrar']))
{ 
$IDalumn = "";
$nomalumn ="";
$apealumn ="";
$IDalumn = $_POST['IdAlu'];
$nomalumn = $_POST['NomA'];
$apealumn = $_POST['ApeA'];
$IDgrado = $_POST["IDgrado"];
$fechaingre = $_POST["FechaIngre"];


$query1 = "INSERT INTO matricula(IDalumno,IDgrado,FechaIngreso)VALUES 
('$IDalumn','$IDgrado','$fechaingre')";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO alumno(IDalumno,Nombres,Apellidos)VALUES 
('$IDalumn','$nomalumn','$apealumn')";
$Create = mysqli_query($conexion,$query1);
$Create1 = mysqli_query($conexion,$query2);

mysqli_close($conexion);

}
```

Here is the HTML code:
The variables get the correct values

```
<table>  
        <ul> 
          <li>
              <input name="IdAlu" id="IdAlu" type="text" maxlength="5"> 
Digite la identificacion del alumno: 
          </li>
          <li>
              <input name="NomA" id="NomA" type="text" maxlength="40"> 
Digite Los nombres del alumno:
          </li>
          <li>
              <input name="ApeA" id="ApeA" type="text" maxlength="40"> 
Digite Los apellidos del alumno:
          </li>
          <li>
              <input name="IDgrado" id="IDgrado" type="text" 
maxlength="2" > Digite la identificacion de grado al que ingresa el 
alumno:
          </li>
          <li>
              <input name="FechaIngre" id="FechaIngre" type="date"> 
 Digite la fecha en la que ingresa el alumno:
          </li>
            <input type="submit" name="Registrar" value="AGREGAR"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Actualizar" Value="ACTUALIZAR">


        </ul>    
      </table>
```

Comment: This should have been posted in https://es.stackoverflow.com/ given you're a member there and most of us don't know Spanish.

Comment: I didn't know that exist this page in spanish, thanks :)

Comment: I think that is only simple quotes is fast solved

Comment: @RamsésFernández well seeing you're Spanish also, you and the OP know what `fechaingre` means, I don't and most of the others don't. I don't feel that's fair for everyone. Tell me, what does `fechaingre` mean in English? Not to mention the rest of the words.

Comment: date of admission, and yes you have reason it's not fair.

Answer (score 1):

`$fechaingre` put here simple quotes as `'$fechaingre'` and add `$IDalumn`

```
     $query1 = "INSERT INTO matricula(IdGrado,IDalumno,FechaIngreso) 
VALUES('$IDgrado','$IDalumn','$fechaingre')";
```

If you need parse date do this:

```
 $fechaingre=new DateTime($fechaingre);
 $fechaingre=$fechaingre->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Thanks i didn't see that, but still without inserting

Comment: What have type you on databade as FechaIngreso

Comment: The type is "date"

Comment: MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Comment: Yes, how can i change it?

Comment: See my anwers now

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Proyecto/Codigo/Alumno.php on line 80

What can i do?

Comment: Try now with the new modify

Comment: Man, ur the best, but it still with out work, only Alumno Table

Answer (score 1):

The  matricula table has 3 columns defined in the query, but in the VALUES() you only provide 2 values. There is no value for IDalumno.

Comment: Ok i made the changes and see the orden in the database but only insert in the Alumno table...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this and post if any error message is being printed?

```
<?PHP
include 'Conexion.php';
if(isset($_POST['Registrar']))
{ 
$IDalumn = "";
$nomalumn ="";
$apealumn ="";
$IDalumn = $_POST['IdAlu'];
$nomalumn = $_POST['NomA'];
$apealumn = $_POST['ApeA'];
$IDgrado = $_POST["IDgrado"];
$fechaingre = $_POST["FechaIngre"];


$query1 = "INSERT INTO matricula(IDalumno,IDgrado,FechaIngreso)VALUES 
('{$IDalumn}','{$IDgrado}','{$fechaingre}')";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO alumno(IDalumno,Nombres,Apellidos) VALUES 
('{$IDalumn}','{$nomalumn}','{$apealumn}')";

if (!(@mysqli_query ($query1, $conexion))) {
    print '<br><b style="color:red">Exception:</b> ';
    throw new Exception(showerror());
}
else {
    if (!(@mysqli_query ($query2, $conexion))) {
        print '<br><b style="color:red">Exception:</b> ';
        throw new Exception(showerror());
    } else {
        print "<br> <b>Record inserted successfully!";
    }
}

//$Create = mysqli_query($conexion,$query1);
//$Create1 = mysqli_query($conexion,$query2);

mysqli_close($conexion);

}
?>
```

Comment: Man, Thanks a lot, i found the error, it was this:
$query1 = "INSERT INTO matricula(IDalumno,IDgrado,FechaIngreso) VALUES('{$IDalumn}','{$IDgrado}','{$fechaingre}')";

Left one space between Values: ) VALUES (

Comment: Sure man, appreciate the response and pls accept the answer if it resolved your concern. Thanks.